# Filling up arrays with User inputs

Tags: c, arrays, input

So I created an array and I'm using a For loop to fill the array with values using "scanf". I know i can't use "get()" so scanf appears to be my only option.

```
printf("Enter 4 numbers:");
getchar();
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    a[i] = scanf("%d", &input);
}
```

Here is my new code after i have received help on how to scan in an element. i made a few other minor changes also.

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
}
```

Comment: With the help of @Kraken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scanf("%d", &input)
```

The above line of code will prompt the user for an input and then add the integer value in input. Now, assigning the above with your a[i] does not make any sense.

What you can do is, instead of using input as a carrier of input, put the input from user directly into your array

```
scanf("%d", &a[i]);
```

Surely, the above line of code will be in a for loop.

Cheers

Comment: Your explanation made a lot more sense to me then just giving me the answer. so Thank you @kraken

Answer (score 0):

That is not how `scanf` works. First, you don't need `getchar()`. Second, `scanf` puts its output inside the argument not as a return value. Use the following instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int len = 4, i;
    int a[4];

    printf("Enter 4 numbers:");
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        scanf("%d", a + i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
     scanf("%d", &a[i]);
}
```

`scanf()` returns the number of elements read, not the element read. read [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm)